# rbind all given columns within a list

Tags: r, list, rbind, read.csv

I am reading a variable number of .csv files, all contained in the present working directory, into a list, and would like to rbind the 2nd column of each of these .csv files.

The files in the working directory look like this:

```
150601_0001.csv
150601_0002.csv
150601_0003.csv
etc.
```

I have the following code to read them all into a list for any given number of files in the directory:
(code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17609714/2248376))

```
myfiles <- dir(pattern = "\\.(csv|CSV)$", full.names = TRUE) # get filenames and paths
myfiles_data <- lapply(myfiles, data.table::fread) # read data from files, quickly
head(myfiles_data[[1]]) # validate file reading
names(myfiles_data) <- myfiles # assign names to list items
```

This works perfectly fine so far, and I get all the data into a pretty list:

```
> myfiles_data
$`./150601_0001.csv`
       X     Y Z
  1:   1 67.81 1
  2:   2 68.52 1
  3:   3 69.66 1
 ---            
250: 250 50.02 1
251: 251 50.58 1
252: 252 51.16 1

$`./150601_0002.csv`
       X     Y Z
  1:   1 70.77 2
  2:   2 70.54 2
  3:   3 70.47 2
 ---            
250: 250 51.00 2
251: 251 51.17 2
252: 252 51.43 2

$`./150601_0003.csv`
       X     Y Z
  1:   1 68.32 3
  2:   2 67.80 3
  3:   3 67.33 3
 ---            
250: 250 50.58 3
251: 251 50.68 3
252: 252 50.77 3
```

Now I want to rbind on the second column of each data set. The following code gives me a list with only the second columns (data was abbreviated for visual purposes):

```
> lapply(myfiles_data, `[[`, 2)
$`./150601_0001.csv`
  [1] 67.81 68.52 69.66 ...
  ...
[241] ... 52.85 51.85 50.90

$`./150601_0002.csv`
  [1] 70.77  70.54  70.47 ...
  ...
[241] ... 51.00  51.17  51.43

$`./150601_0003.csv`
  [1] 68.32 67.80 67.33 ...
  ...
[241] ... 50.58 50.68 50.77
```

How may I apply rbind() to all of these in one shot?

Comment: you can also do `Reduce(rbind, lapply(myfiles_data, `[[`, 2))` or `t(data.frame(lapply(myfiles_data, `[[`, 2)))`

Comment: The `t()` solution is is working, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually this does not give me a valid matrix:
`> attributes(z)
$dim
[1]  54 252

> attributes(z1)
$dim
[1]  55 252

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
NULL

$dimnames[[2]]
NULL`

(this is `z` standing for the `rbind()` done by hand on csv files inputted one by one, and `z1` is for the automatic list method + your `t()` solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont have reputation to add a comment so adding an answer

try this to rbind all data into one dataframe

```
Output<-do.call(rbind, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
unlist(lapply(myfiles_data, `[[`, 2))
```