# how to get rid of empty dimnames in a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, attributes

I have two matrixes that look the same when I display them. They are both matrixes:

```
> is.matrix(z)
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(z1)
[1] TRUE
```

But the `attributes()` are clearly different, and one of them looks like it's still a list, and displays one more row:

```
> attributes(z)
$dim
[1]  54 252

> attributes(z1)
$dim
[1]  55 252

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
NULL

$dimnames[[2]]
NULL
```

The latter gives me an error in any downstream application. The additional row seems to be a separate problem (?) so I'm looking into that, but is there any way to get rid of the `$dimnames` information?

Comment: It's _very_ unlikely that the presence of the `dimnames` is giving you the errors. They very likely arise from other issues.

Comment: Oh, ok... that information in itself is really helpful, so thank you a lot for your comment. Indeed, I still get the error even after eliminating dimnames.

Comment: You should try to build a minimal example that reproduces the error and then post another question.

Comment: I guess also that you should upvote/accept the answers you received, since you asked for eliminating the `dimnames` and the answers actually do that. People have lost some time to help you and I guess that they deserve some reward (even if that doesn't solve your actual problem).

Comment: Sorry, I was about to do precisely that... thank you for reminding me that I just lost everyone's time...

Comment: I just found out where the trouble was coming from; one of the column names in the original data set was wrong. For my defence I will say that 55 files is a lot to check by hand. Not even worthy of sharing, but at least I learnt how to get rid of dimnames, which can be useful ^^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward:

```
dimnames(z1) <- NULL
```

Tested with the following code:

```
z <- z1 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
dimnames(z1) <- list(NULL, NULL)
attributes(z)
# $dim
# [1] 10 10
attributes(z1)
# $dim
# [1] 10 10

# $dimnames
# $dimnames[[1]]
# NULL

# $dimnames[[2]]
# NULL

dimnames(z1) <- NULL
attributes(z1)

# $dim
# [1] 10 10
```

Now my question would rather be, where does the empty dimnames attribute come from?

Comment: Thanks! One of the matrixes was created by `rbind()` on certain columns of multiple data frames, while the other one I was testing a method to automate the reading of all csv files in a given folder into a list, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558630/rbind-all-given-columns-within-a-list/31561696#31561696

Comment: As @nicola suggested, `persp()` still doesn't want my matrix even after eliminating dimnames. `is.numeric()` gives me `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
mat <- matrix(1, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
attributes(mat)
# $dim
# [1] 1 1
# 
# $dimnames
# $dimnames[[1]]
# NULL
# 
# $dimnames[[2]]
# NULL

attr(mat, "dimnames") <- NULL
attributes(mat)
# $dim
# [1] 1 1
```